# How to insert shapefiles into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, shapefile

I am trying to find this `shp2mysql` tool. But all I found was a PHP implementation. There is any other version available in the internet?

Comment: Why is PHP implementation a problem?

Comment: Not a problem, it's just that I am not comfortable with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a solution](http://www.kartografie.nl/rimapper/) for [download](http://www.kartografie.nl/rimapper/code/shp2mysql_0_4.zip). (Windows version)

The readme says it needs Cygwin, but I just executed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you would want to insert files into a database, but if you had to, I don't see why you can't use MySQL's BINARY or BLOB data type (I can't recall if a .shp file is binary or text). Just read in the file using [insert your favorite language] and construct the appropriate MySQL query statement to add it to the database - it's pretty easy, almost trivial.

A better solution would be to store the file in your file system and record a path to it in your database, allowing you to open the file and read it when needed.